# Search for string in names of all tables in sql management studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there any way to search for string in names of all tables in sql management studio 2008? I don't want complicated query just short key, for example ctrl+f -> "test" -> find -> screen with links to all the tables with "test" in its name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly recommend the free [Sql Hunting Dog](http://www.sql-hunting-dog.com/) plugin for Management Studio for this.  It has Ctrl+D as a default shortcut to start searching.

Comment: So useful this plugin. Thanks a lot for recommending it! I've remapped  it to Ctrl+Shift+N, like Resharper "Search files" thingy and my brain is happy now.

Comment: I installed it but when I press "Ctrl+D" nothing happens (well I hear a little "ding" meaning I pressed something invalid) - Are there additional steps to activate the plugin that are not listed on the site, or is it just out or date?

Comment: It just works for me with "Ctrl+D".  Verify that you see a menu item called "Hunting Dog" in the Tools menu.

Answer (score 6):

So basically you're looking for something like this?

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name LIKE '%yourStringHere%'
-- AND schema_name = 'dbo' -- in case you need the Schema too
```

Comment: yes but just with ctrl+f not with 3 lines of code ... its too complicated

Answer (score 0):

Kahn's answer is probably best (even though it's not the answer you want).  However, if you want to do this using the GUI, you can right click on Tables, select Filter, and hit Filter Settings.  That opens up a dialog where you can add criteria to Filter by (like name).

There is no CTRL Key shrotcut to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but you can do this in native SSMS 2008 with the "Object Explorer Details" (Press F7 or found under View > Object Explorer Details)

You can search any directory you select, also allows use of wild cards ('%', '_', '[a-z]', etc.)

Answer (score -2):

show tables like '%YourStringHere%';

above query works for MySql. I checked it.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38564181/edit) to explain why this solves the user's question.